# redirect_url should be an absolute url

Tags: facebook, registration

I am installing FB reg on my web app (and testing locally).

I am putting up this:

```
<div class="auth">
    <script language="javascript">
$(function(){
    var root = $('#fb-root');
    if ((!root) || (!root.length)){
        $('body').append('<div id="fb-root"></div>');
    }
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        console.log('fbAsyncInit');
        FB.init({
            appId      : '111...', // App ID
            channelUrl : 'http://www.wonderlandlabs.com/channel.html', // Channel File
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });
    };
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));
})
```

... and getting this error:

"'redirect_uri' should be an absolute url."

Why is this so?

Comment: What is throwing that error message? `Fb.init`?

Comment: http://www.evernote.com/shard/s198/sh/34ce830e-8ec0-471b-851a-a405d2f17d73/0439fa021192116ffc09517639be7740 shows the error as displayed on screen (after a few seconds of "blue progress bar". Note: the url is acutally on my local system; I've "tricked" the /etc/hosts file to redirect wonderlandlabs.com to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Why aren't you using `localhost`? Open the chrome developers tools and select the network tab, in it check the requests to facebook to see what `redirect_uri` and `origin` were sent